# Is it possible to fetch hot topics from subreddit from a specific time frame?

Tags: api, reddit

I'm currently fetching top posts in JSON format with code like this:

`https://www.reddit.com/r/sub/top.json?t=week`

I would like to do similar with hot posts, but seems like it doesn't work, unless I'm missing something

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `/hot` endpoint to get the hot posts for a subreddit. The `/top` endpoint allows you to specify a time period for the top posts, but the `/hot` endpoint does not have this option.

Here is an example URL that you can use to get the hot posts for a subreddit called `sub`:

```
https://www.reddit.com/r/sub/hot.json
```

Keep in mind that the `/hot` endpoint only returns the default set of hot posts for a subreddit, which is determined by Reddit's algorithm. If you want more control over the posts that are returned, you may want to use the `/search` endpoint instead. You can use the `q` query parameter to specify a search query, and the `sort` query parameter to specify how the results should be sorted (e.g. `relevance`, `hot`, `top`, etc.).

Here is an example URL that you can use to search for hot posts in a subreddit called sub:

```
https://www.reddit.com/r/sub/search.json?q=&sort=hot
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess you've answered my question that there is no way to sort hot topics by a specific timeframe

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/#GET_search
you can use `t` param,  it has to be one of (hour, day, week, month, year, all)

Comment: I've experimented it with `t` param and it always returns the same result no matter what